# R-Customized tooltip in networkD3::sankeyNetwork

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, sankey-diagram, networkd3

We have created  sankey diagram to show flow between different cities via `networkD3::sankeyNetwork()` in R.
We have received client requirement to show "state" name corresponding to city on tooltip/hover of sankey node.

In following code we want to show State value on tool-tip(hover) of node

```r
library(shiny)
library(networkD3)
library(shinydashboard)
value <-  c(12,21,41,12,81)
source <- c(4,1,5,2,1)
target <- c(0,0,1,3,3)

edges2 <- data.frame(cbind(value,source,target))

names(edges2) <- c("value","source","target")
indx  <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5)
ID    <- c('CITY1','CITY2','CITY3','CITY4','CITY5','CITY6')
State <- c( 'IL','CA','FL','NW','GL','TX')
nodes <-data.frame(cbind(ID,indx,State))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidPage(
      sankeyNetworkOutput("simple")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  
  output$simple <- renderSankeyNetwork({
    sankeyNetwork(Links = edges2, Nodes = nodes,
                  Source = "source", Target = "target",
                  Value = "value",  NodeID = "ID" 
                  ,units = " " )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As the `networkD3` package does not provide a customized tooltip feature, please suggest how it can be achieved via javascript or some other way in `networkD3::sankeyNetwork()`.

Comment: Could you please give a reproducible example?

Comment: Reproducible code  is already mentioned above in description, Variable "State" should show on  tooltip. Can you please check and suggest any way achieving results ?.

Comment: `nodes <-data.frame(cbind(ID,indx,population))` these objects are not defined!

Comment: Thanks for correcting, its updated now, Can you please  review now

Comment: Would you be okay if i try some other library for sankey or should it be only this?

Comment: we have completed  app development using NETWORKD3 which is in production, can you suggest any way using networkd3

Comment: Sure, I'm trying! The problem is the javascript automatically takes the node name and it's beyond `networkD3`'s implementation, so checking how can this be done.

Comment: Thanks for your help sir!!

Answer (score 6):

You can use a technique similar to this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45918897/4389763). Save the output of the `sankeyNetwork` function, then add back in the data that gets stripped out, then use `htmlwidgets::onRender` to add some JavaScript to modify the tooltip text of the nodes...

```
library(shiny)
library(networkD3)
library(shinydashboard)
value <-  c(12,21,41,12,81)
source <- c(4,1,5,2,1)
target <- c(0,0,1,3,3)

edges2 <- data.frame(cbind(value,source,target))

names(edges2) <- c("value","source","target")
indx  <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5)
ID    <- c('CITY1','CITY2','CITY3','CITY4','CITY5','CITY6')
State <- c( 'IL','CA','FL','NW','GL','TX')
nodes <-data.frame(cbind(ID,indx,State))

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
    dashboardBody(
        fluidPage(
            sankeyNetworkOutput("simple")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {


    output$simple <- renderSankeyNetwork({
        sn <- sankeyNetwork(Links = edges2, Nodes = nodes,
                      Source = "source", Target = "target",
                      Value = "value",  NodeID = "ID" 
                      ,units = " " )

        # add the states back into the nodes data because sankeyNetwork strips it out
        sn$x$nodes$State <- nodes$State

        # add onRender JavaScript to set the title to the value of 'State' for each node
        sn <- htmlwidgets::onRender(
            sn,
            '
            function(el, x) {
                d3.selectAll(".node").select("title foreignObject body pre")
                .text(function(d) { return d.State; });
            }
            '
        )

        # return the result
        sn
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for great solution!!.It worked exactly how I wanted, however I have replaced "title foreignObject body pre" by "title" to make it worked.